# Help with LaTeX equivalent of this .docx file

Tags: fonts, templates

So, I cooked up a template for CV in MS Word. I wanted to do it in LaTeX, but couldn't since I  have just started learning it. After saving the MS Word document as .pdf I was disappointed with the quality of the font and uncontrollable typesetting in general. So, I went on to do the same in LaTeX. However, the overwhelming amount of commands and numerous roadblocks had me believe that I am dealing with something far beyond a beginner's level. Hence, I turned here for help. [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwwPq3L4xpmDb3hEcmNPWUlkdmM/edit?usp=sharing) is the .docx format of the file. (The original font was CMU Serif, Google drive messes it up a little). [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwwPq3L4xpmDc1FtMlNpaU01ZDg/edit?usp=sharing) is the output I desire through LaTeX.
Any head start / hints as to how to go about starting it with relevant tutorials / lectures would be of great help.

Comment: One nice thing about TeX systems: TeX seems to make it more difficult to make things that look like this. IMHO, I would look for a different layout…

Comment: @SeanAllred: Isn't there any easy way around it? I mean, I am totally new. I may be missing a lot of things here, or mistaking simple things as horrendously tough.

Comment: @jigsawmnc: There is also this [cv template](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_resume_cv_latex_example.php) by Ted Pavlic that you may find useful

Comment: Well, you can always use the Official European Curriculum Vitae style: Europass http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions